# Can't access Facebook configuration page

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to access the Facebook config page for my bot and I keep getting "Sad bot is sad... can't find a bot named bot_name"

Is anyone having issues with the platform right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're not having any portal specific problems. If you want to share your bot handle with us at BotFramework@microsoft.com I can see if there's anything interesting in our logs.

-- just a note, we were actually having portal problems, it was just impacting only one box in one datacenter making it erratic to track down.  Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's team solved it, as it's showed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1254).